# connect two queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to use the data of the first query into the second query to get the right result, but I cannot get it done. Who can help me with this.

```
     SELECT  [Project Nr], Task, TaskDate
     FROM    (
     SELECT   MSP_EpmProject_UserView.[Project Nr]
        ,MAX(CASE   WHEN [Task Type tempress] = 'Packed' 
                    THEN [Taskdeadline] 
                END) AS Pack
        ,MAX(CASE   WHEN [Task Type tempress] = 'Leave Production' 
                    THEN [Taskdeadline]
                END) AS [Leave Production]
        ,MAX(CASE   WHEN [Task Type tempress] = 'Flight Date' 
                    THEN [Taskdeadline]
                END) AS [Flight Date]
     FROM    MSP_EpmProject_UserView 
        LEFT JOIN MSP_EpmTask_UserView 
            ON MSP_EpmProject_UserView.ProjectUID = MSP_EpmTask_UserView.ProjectUID 
        LEFT JOIN MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView 
            ON MSP_EpmTask_UserView.TaskUID = MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView.TaskUID 
        LEFT JOIN MSP_EpmResource_UserView 
            ON MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView.ResourceUID = MSP_EpmResource_UserView.ResourceUID 
     WHERE (MSP_EpmTask_UserView.TaskIsProjectSummary = 0) 
     GROUP BY MSP_EpmProject_UserView.[Project Nr]

     ) data

     UNPIVOT        (
      TaskDate
      for [Task] in ([Pack],[Leave Vaassen],[Flight Date])
     ) piv
```

This Part of the query has to use the data of the query above:

```
   select 
      * 
   from 
      M AllData
   inner join (
     select 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by TaskDate) as ProductionOrder, 
        [Project Nr] 
     from 
        M
     where
         task = 'Leave Production'
    )
    ProductionOrder
    on ProductionOrder.[Project Nr] = AllData.[Project Nr]
    Order by
    ProductionOrder
```

Comment: "*cannot get it done*" is not a valid error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you are talking about Correlated subqueries. You can find some info on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187638(v=sql.105).aspx. Whole point is that an outer query is connected to each iteration of the inner query. I hope i understood your question well?

Answer (score 1):

Well you have left out a lot of important details such as what DBMS you are using and how you want to use the first query, but if you are using SQL Server 2005+ I would recommend looking at [Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
with myCTE as
(
   --Your first query
)

--You can now use myCTE in another query...
SELECT * FROM myCTE
```